# Youtube-dl how to get a direct download link to the merged file without creating a temp file on server

Tags: merge, youtube-dl

Is there any way to create a direct download link to the merged file without creating a temp file on the server in youtube-dl?

```
youtube-dl -f 255+160 https://youtu.be/p-flvm1szbI
```

The above code will merge the file and output the merged file.

I want to allow users to directly download the merged file to their computers -- without creating any temp file on my server. Is this possible?

(Creating a temp file and then letting the user download it is already possible.)

Comment: Can you please provide any examples of what you have tried before?

Comment: @pathurs. I haven't tried anything as in I don't have any idea

Comment: yt-dl will download audio and video file (temp files) seperately. Then merge them into a single file and delete those temporary files. so, what you mean `without creating any temp file on my server` ? You don't want those temporary files or the merged file?

Comment: Yes I know how does that work. but I'm asking is there anyway for me to merge these audio + video files and get a stream link which I can let any other user to download it without using my server bandwidth.? I'm talking about the final output.